# yahoo finance api in java

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

i have to get stock quotes from yahoo finance api n use it in my app
do i need to include any jar to use yahoo finance api?
i referred

http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/General-Discussion-at-YDN/Re-Using-Yahoo-Finance-API-Not/1250246255000-0b82f8f0-7f48-3af2-8fe2-e73a138cbfaa

which has a code to get the stock quotes but it is not using the api...

i also referred the following sites as given in

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10635616/how-to-use-yahoo-finance-api-in-java#comment13787113_10635616

but i would like to get a head start in the same for coding... do i need to include any jar for this api in my java app? by referring to the above sites i came to know that the quotes come in excel sheet so how do i store the excel sheet in a particular location through code?

Comment: You refer to your own question covering the same topic? To me this seems to be a duplicate!

Comment: sorry but yes this is a duplicate but more specific

Comment: @z22: In the future, it is better to update a question than to duplicate it. I'm voting to close your old one.

Comment: sorry for bothering you, i ll be more careful next time

Comment: The code is already mentioned on the link that you provided. Did you even tried that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read the code on that link?

From the link provided by you:

```
url = new URL("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=RHT+MSFT&f=sb2b3jk");
```

the code on the page itself provides a solution.

No you don't need to add any external jars to use this.

The code to store the file is also mentioned in the same link.

Comment: yes i worked out that code...its working now...thanks